# Jackson Serialization excludes fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

First of all I want to give you a bit of context.

We have an **interface A** which is implemented by **class B.** **Class B** also **extends** *abstract* **class C**.

What we usually return when the requests are called (rest GET endpoint) are the values in B and the values in all the classes that form the hierarchy (D extending B and so on).

**B contains getters** to access these values. **These getters are NOT DEFINED in the A interface.**
But the response works, the values are converted into a JSON so there's no problem so far. Jackson is able to call the getters and create the JSON based on them

Now we're upgrading Jackson to a newer version from 2.6.7. We tried 2.10.3 and upward.

**The problem is that those getters are not being serialized anymore**. If we define them in the interface is ok but the risk of doing this in our context is high.

Does anyone know why with the newer versions of Jackson the getters which are not defined in the interface are ignored?
Is there a configuration, tweak or something which can force its previous behavior?

**Later Edit 1**

Important to note **how the objects are created**:
*Interface A obj = new Class C()* or whichever is needed from the hierarchy;

**Later Edit 2**

**Maybe it helps also providing the information that Spring was updated from version 4.0.0 to 5.3.0. The application uses
Spring-mvc, Spring-core, it's a non-spring-boot application.**

The dependencies used:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.databind}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.databind}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any custom serialization configuration for your types? In a polymorphic model, there must be certainly one as otherwise custom types mapping won't be possible. A simple example with an interface being implemented by one (or many) type(s) would fairly work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back since 2018 or so the exploitation of serialization validation limitations in authenticity were being abused and led to vulnerability patches.
These were called “serialization gadgets”; but by the time the vulnerability reports made it into public eye - many different serialization frameworks and libraries,including Jackson, had already distributed bundled packages with their installers.

For Java - some example datatypes which may be exploitable may be:

```
java.lang.Object
java.io.Serializable
java.util.Comparable
```

For Jackson - around 2.10.x a change to serialization was released, but I was unable to find a specific reference to patching Gadgets.

Typically the resolution is to blacklist serialization of Classes which contain such datatypes. Luckily, the developers often include a flag (like a ToS agreement) which you can specify to re-enable serialization of these Classes.

Unfortunately, I last programmed in Java 5 years ago - but based on quick reading I imagine the "flag" would include some form of `annotation decorator` or xml config tag.

Comment: Thank you for this information I will check this

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution - if not by end of week I will throw a bounty for you :)

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind! I will keep researching. No success yet

Comment: Yeah well this is more complicated than I thought :D
The reason is also the fact that the objects used as a response are quite complex and finding a solution without interfering with what's there is  harder than I thought. The risks implied by interfering with the response is high  since the codebase is huge and not everything is completely tested.

Comment: I just realized I do not see a Jackson.databind in your dependencies....do you have access to your objectMapper packaged in your serialization?

Comment: You will probably want to check out Jackson's MixIn packages so you can ensure that you're telling the serializer to use reflection to access the fields of the abstract classes (class C in your example) when deserializing.

Comment: yes, there is the jackson-databind dependency defined also. I will have a look at MixIn